# What is this sideways capital I component with an x in the middle on a schematic for an Intel chipset?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, schematics, components, schematic

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/198DksAVJf0nyaOG2yW2pxVeaP0N1_whp/view) is the schematic

[image]

The compoent in blue -- it appears to vaguely resemble a 0 ohm resistor. Is it a TVS diode?

Comment: It's widely used across the whole schematic. And mostly it's marked as a 0 Ohm resistor. Maybe they are using this symbol for a 0 Ohm link -- kinda a jumper to make life easy for PCB designers.

Comment: I've seen weird stuff like this before for evaluation boards, where you have some big QFP with a great number of pins in the middle, surrounded by 2,54mm socket strips on all four sides. The weird symbols would then correspond to the socket strip number, essentially jumpers, where some pins may already be shorted on the PCB. Not necessarily the case here though.

Comment: @Lundin it appears to be a jumper, yes